# Rails app only works on 3000 port, DigitalOcean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, digital-ocean

I used **One-click installation** to install Rails app on **Digital Ocean**.
Then I added some layout to application, changed root page and other things.

Checked my server for changes, but there was none of them. Even If I deleted application controller it worked just fine.

**What I tried:**

Using SSH access executed `rails s` command inside `home` folder.

Then visited my server IP with port 3000 and then all changes worked there.But still not on main IP adress.

I did not change anything in config files or something in ports.

What could cause this weird error?
I tried to contact DO but they said this error is outside their support scope.

**Error logs:**

*Nginx error log is empty*

*Unicorn log:*

```
I, [2015-04-18T14:07:30.752314 #901]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
I, [2015-04-18T14:07:30.760934 #904]  INFO -- : worker=2 ready
I, [2015-04-18T14:07:30.782024 #907]  INFO -- : worker=3 ready
I, [2015-04-18T14:07:30.831101 #898]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
```

Nginx access log shows last access
...

```
[18/Apr/2015:15:36:05 +0000] "GET /assets/rails.png HTTP/1.1
```

3 mins after my droplet was created. But I definitely accessed to it afterwards.

Also tried to create new droplet with the same setup and error was still there.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post your nginx config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a DigitalOcean Droplet with RoR+Passenger, if so, you might have to check nginx configuration or passenger configuration.
This has to do with the fact Passenger and Nginx are going to load your RoR-project and Nginx is on port 80. Therefore, running `rails s` probably won't work, as port 80 is occupied by nginx process.

Comment: I have droplet with Unicorn + Nginx and I created other droplet with the same setup 5 minutes before this one and that works like charm.

Comment: You might want to check error logs from Unicorn, Rails and Nginx in that case. Does that give any relevant information?